# onclick use button and svg icon doesn work

Tags: javascript, html, css

when i click the SVG with red background it doesn't work but if i click outside the svg area it works, and if i use normal text it also works fine.

the button appears to be hindered by SVG.

my question is why using SVG doesn't work, but using text works and what if I want it to work?

css :

```
<style>
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
}

.dropdown {
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 160px;
  overflow: auto;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

.show {display: block;}
```

html :

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">
    <svg viewBox='0 0 10 8' width='40' style="background:red;">
        <path d='M1 1h8M1 4h 8M1 7h8' stroke='#000' stroke-width='2' stroke-linecap='round'/>
    </svg>
  </button>
  
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Home</a>
    <a href="#">About</a>
    <a href="#">Contact</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

javascript :

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SVG does not work as a click area in most browsers. What you do is to put the following on your svg to make it "transparent for clicks" so to speak, or the correct term and what it does is actually make it non clickable.

```
.dropbtn > svg {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```